# How do I write the regex that will match min or min=1?

Tags: regex

I have two urls like `https://xxx.xxx.xxxxx?min` and `https://xxx.xxx.xxx?min=1`. I want to write a regex that will match the first url or the second url.

I have tried writing a regex

```
https://xxx.xxx.xxx(\?[a-z]{3}|\?[a-z]{3}|=1)
```

and

```
https://xxx.xxx.xxx(\?min|\?min=1)
```

but those didn't work. The expected result is a regex that matches `https://xxx.xxx.xxxxx?min` or `https://xxx.xxx.xxx?min=1`.

Comment: So the only difference between the patterns is `=1` at the end?

Comment: You seem to have different number of `x`s (5 `x`s in the first url after the second `.`). Is that intentional?

Comment: Use a URL parser if you want this to be reliable. If you must use a regex, you could use something similar to this: `https:\/\/xxx\.xxx\.xxx\?min(?:=1)?`.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the question, the regex `\?min` should match both. If you need a pattern that will match anything with `?min` embedded you can use `.*\?min.*`

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica It will also a match a lot of other things, which I suspect, isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: @AmalMurali: OP can use that as a basis for whatever. For example, `https:\/\/[x.]*\?min.*` but I suspect that the `x`s are supposed to be alpha or alphanumeric. Still, OP's going to have to add to this.

Comment: Try using anchors, an alternation and a optional non capturing group `^https://xxx\.xxx\.(?:xxxxx|xxx)\?[a-z]{3}(?:=1)?$` See https://regex101.com/r/KV4p34/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to escape the slashes in the regex.

Plus, this one should do the trick to accept only your cases:

```
https:\/\/(.*?)\?(min|min=1)$
```

Please, try it.

Comment: If you need also the start to exactly match, just add ^ at the beginning -> ^https:\/\/(.*?)\?(min|min=1)$

Answer (score 1):

If you want only match the provided urls this regex can be useful

```
/^https:\/\/.+?\?(min=1|min)$/mg
```

> **^** asserts position at start of a line
>
> **$** asserts position at the end of a line

Modifiers:

> **m modifier**: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each
>   line (not only begin/end of string)
>
> **g modifier**: global. All matches
>   (don't return after first match)

[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/C3xGSq/1)

Answer (score 0):

It does not match because your URL is `https://xxx.xxx.xxxxx?min` but regex is `https://xxx.xxx.xxx(\?min|\?min=1)` (notice there are 5 `x` chars in the input and 3 in regex).

You should also replace `.` with `\.` in regex because `.` matches *all characters*.

Answer (score 0):

Make `=1` part optional:

```
^https://xxx.xxx.xxx\?min(=1)?$
```

Comment: @blow Fixed! 